# How to convert this Mysql to pdo

Tags: mysql, pdo

```
*$insert =mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('$username','$password')")
        or die("error");*
```

can anyone please convert this piece of mysql code to pdo.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us what You have tried to do?

Comment: See if this helps : http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a PHP expert, but here's an example based on your code:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
$result = $db->exec("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('$username','$password')");
$insertId = $db->lastInsertId();
```

Try it and let me know if it works.